# Job Card Device TimeOut Issue in D365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I am not sure if this is the right forum for this question, but I am trying my luck to get answers.

Below is an issue which i have .
- Our users are accessing Dynamics 365 Job card device on iPad through web browser
- There is a session time out after X hours of inactivity. 
- Users have to login again and resume their work.

Is there any way that powerapps can help to keep the session alive .

I  would like to get suggestions on how this can be achieved .

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure as I have not worked with Job card device, but in dynamics this is how we do. There is an system settings under setting Tab.

[Ref Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/user-session-management) will give you more insight to it.

[image]